# List attachments as menu items in ribbon group

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

I am developing a [Office.js addin](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office) for Outlook. My goal is to display a menu button in the ribbon group whereas the menu items should be the attachments of the mail item currently active.

I am aware of this restriction:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/13225365-support-dynamic-content-in-add-in-commands-ribbon

I was still wondering if there is a work-around since the list of attachments is already available at the addin's initialization. So I am not trying to dynamically modify the list during the addin's execution, I just need to provide the list of menu items at it's startup (in the manifest).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The ribbon commands are not initialized when your add-in launches, they are all predefined within your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your feedback. Learning about the new requirements add-in developers have, helps us continue to enable great scenarios on our platform. Currently the feature you requested is not part of the product. However we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Features on user-voice are also considered when we go through our planning process.

Link to user voice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins.

Thanks again for your feedback,
Outlook Engineering Team